# How to make a unique username when using FB connect

Tags: php, facebook

Hi everyone I want make sure the username is unique!

First I get there username and check if existing already. If not add them to the database, but if the username is taken I will add number behind it.

Example: `JoshSmith, JoshSmith1`

If there is no username the user still use the `id` version. I will get there first and last name. And then repeat the above steps.

The problem: If `JoshSmith` is taken I will add number behind it, but if `JoshSmith1` is also taken.

If I use

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%JoshSmith%'
```

it will return names like `JoshSmithing` and this is wrong. If I use

```
MATCH () AGAINST ()
```

returns the same results.

First I thought to count how many times the username exist and add the number+1

```
JoshSmith14
```

But that will be wrong.

Comment: Why would that be wrong? FB does that. (FB and million other sites, that is)

Comment: It will be wrong, because I cant count the usernames.

Comment: Just strip the number at the end of the string... or, when adding numbers, add an underscore or something, so you get `Joe_1`, `Joe_2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) to filter JoshSmith[numbers] and find biggest number. But, as for me, this is bad way, as you will have a lot of loading to your DB server. I think that it would be better to store counts in some table (especially if correct numbers are important to you).